# assign() for only one sheet of an array - avoid manual change

Tags: r, arrays, indexing, assign

I have some arrays that I will need to fill in. The names of the arrays are variable, but the same functions will happen to them throughout. Basically I need a way to replace only one "sheet" of an array with another without manually entering the array name. Example below:

```
big_array_1 <- array(dim = c(5,5,10))
big_array_1[,,1] <- sample(c(1:10), 25, replace=T)

big_array_2 <- array(dim = c(5,5,10))
big_array_2[,,1] <- sample(c(40:50), 25, replace=T)


small_array <- array(dim = c(5,5,2))
small_array[,,] <- sample(c(20:30), 50, replace=T)
```

so each big array will have to have its second sheet (the third dimension) replaced by the second sheet of the small array, but I want to just be able to set a number (i.e. big array "1" or "2") to make this work in my code instead of change the name manually every time.

```
# So I know I can do this, but I want to avoid manually changing the "_1" to "_2" when I run the script
big_array_1[,,2] <- small_array[,,2]

# instead, I'm hoping I can use a variable and some kind of assign()
arraynumber <- 1


# but this gives an error for assigning a non-language object
get(paste0("big_array_",arraynumber))[,,2] <- small_array[,,2]

# and this gives an error for invalid first argument. 
assign(get(paste0("big_array_",arraynumber))[,,2],  small_array[,,2])

# even though get(paste0("big_array_",arraynumber))[,,2] works on its own.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A simple way is to combine all of the `big_array`s and `small-array`s into lists so that big_array[[1]] would be the first big array, etc. Then use `lappy` to run through the lists or write a `for` loop to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you cannot assign values to the result of `get()`. Additionally, it is not advisable to use `assign` even `attach`, `eval`+`parse`, `list2env`, and other environment-changing, dynamic methods that tend to be hard to debug.

As commented, simply use named lists for identically structured objects. Lists can contain *any* object from arrays to data frames to plots without a number limit. Even more, you avoid flooding global environment with separately named objects but work with a handful of lists containing *many* underlying elements which better manages data for assignment or iterative needs.

**Definition**

```
set.seed(8620)

# NAMED LIST OF TWO ARRAYS 
big_array_list <- list(big_array_1 = array(dim = c(5,5,10)),
                       big_array_2 = array(dim = c(5,5,10)))

big_array_list$big_array_1[,,1] <- sample(c(1:10), 25, replace=TRUE)
big_array_list$big_array_2[,,1] <- sample(c(40:50), 25, replace=TRUE)

# NAMED LIST OF ONE ARRAY
small_array_list <- list(small_array_1 = array(sample(c(20:30), 50, replace=TRUE),
                                               dim = c(5,5,2)))
```

**Assignment**

```
# ASSIGN BY FIXED NAME
big_array_list$big_array_1[,,2] <- small_array_list$small_array_1[,,2]
big_array_list$big_array_1[,,2]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   30   29   26   24   23
# [2,]   21   20   22   20   24
# [3,]   27   24   26   30   30
# [4,]   30   26   24   29   25
# [5,]   26   21   26   20   30

# ASSIGN BY DYNAMIC NAME
arraynumber <- 1
big_array_list[[paste0("big_array_",arraynumber)]][,,2] <- small_array_list[[paste0("small_array_",arraynumber)]][,,2]
big_array_list[[paste0("big_array_",arraynumber)]][,,2]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   30   29   26   24   23
# [2,]   21   20   22   20   24
# [3,]   27   24   26   30   30
# [4,]   30   26   24   29   25
# [5,]   26   21   26   20   30

# ASSIGN BY INDEX
big_array_list[[1]][,,2] <- small_array_list[[1]][,,2]
big_array_list[[1]][,,2]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   30   29   26   24   23
# [2,]   21   20   22   20   24
# [3,]   27   24   26   30   30
# [4,]   30   26   24   29   25
# [5,]   26   21   26   20   30
```

**Iterative Needs**

```
# RETURN DIMENSIONS OF EACH big_array
lapply(big_array_list, dim)

# SHOW FIRST 5 ELEMENTS OF EACH big_array
sapply(big_array_list, `[`, 1:5)

# RETURN LIST WHERE ALL big_arrays ARE EQUAL TO small_array 
mapply(`<-`, big_array_list, small_array_list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```